# Ubuntu Extras keyring error

Tags: apt, update-manager, repository, gnupg, signature

Recently I got lots of GPG errors and tried the following methods at various stages:

1. ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3E5C1192
   ```
2. ```
   sudo apt-get install -reinstall ubuntu-extras-keyring
   ```

   (For Ubuntu Extras only)
3. ```
   gpg –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv 3E5C1192
   gpg –export –armor 3E5C1192 | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. ```
   sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update`
   ```
5. ```
   sudo -i   
   apt-get clean
   cd /var/lib/apt 
   mv lists lists.old
   mkdir -p lists/partial  
   apt-get clean 
   apt-get update
   ```

I again got BADSIG error for extras.ubuntu.com today. So, I'm really at a loss what's causing this error to occur time and again. I really want to solve this problem once and for all.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get update` so that we can help you.

Comment: Sadly I now get even more errors for my manually added repositories. Here's the output of my sudo apt-get update: http://paste.ubuntu.com/545647/. I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I think I should also let you know that the errors surfaced after I downloaded all the installed packages to my cache for creating an APTonCD. I'm not sure if it's because of that, though.

Comment: Please confirm: Which **Ubuntu** version, and what repository (country)?

Comment: I'm **not** getting this on **12.04** 32-bit, but it **is** happening on **12.04** 64-bit (both desktop and server).

Comment: Method 5 works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically import all missing GPG keys using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

Comment: @Pawan, is your question answered?

Comment: What level of trust can be assumed for a third-party 'PPA' for keys?