# Apt-get update error: http://extras.ubuntu.com Public key unavailable

Tags: apt

> GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com
>   natty Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified
>   because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192

I think I selected to install things from extras.ubuntu.com when I used the expert mode installer, but I got the above error when doing `apt-get update`. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308760/w-gpg-error-http-ppa-launchpad-net-precise-release-the-following-signatures

Comment: Official repositories like "Ubuntu Extras" are actually linked and have packages. To install this pubkey, merely run `apt-get install ubuntu-extras-keyring` (You can find others with a command like `apt-cache search repo |grep .-keyring` which also works for Debian)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3E5C1192
gpg --export --armor 3E5C1192 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

This could be a solution. From

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-gpg-error-httpextras-ubuntu-com-maverick-release.html

You can also get all launchpad keys automatically using the below method

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

From

[Ubuntu Extras keyring error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18091/ubuntu-extras-keyring-error#24751)

Comment: Had the same problem as above on my 11.10 laptop. What's more, I had an annoying red triangle right next to my battery indicator. Tried a few other suggestions around the internet, but this worked great.

Comment: Wow, that was easy.. I've tried at least 10 other solutions that did nothing if not harm my machine.