# Why am I getting errors today when updating Oneiric PPAs?

Tags: updates, ppa, launchpad

When I update software from terminal with `sudo apt-get update` almost always don't shown errors but this time is different.

What I think is that most of the **ppa** pages has been modified. i.e.
When the update want to find a source goes to `ppa.launchpad.net/.../InRelease` but it tells me that is impossible, so if I open the **URL** and it shows me `Not Found` but if I go to the previously directory *(of the server)* I see a `Release` file.

This doesn't happens to one program but all the **ppa** there I added to my source list. I don't know if its problem of my system or configuration, some changes made to the own ppa's website or what.

What I should do?

- Modify the path from `.../InRelease` to `.../Release`
- Remove this ppa from the source list

---

The complete output errors [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1153804/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Launchpad/PPA system has recently been under heavy maintenance, and this looks like [a scheduled outage, on August 17, 2012.](http://blog.launchpad.net/notifications/launchpad-code-hosting-unavailable-22-00-utc-2012-08-17)
- Everything should be fine once maintenance is complete in a few hours.
- However, some recent maintenance has gone beyond the scheduled window, so please check http://blog.launchpad.net/ for the latest updates, and/or as *tijybba* suggests in the comments, [check their Twitter feed.](https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus)

Comment: Also check their [Twitter](https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus) page for status updates .

Comment: Method 5 (from question, **not** answers) in http://askubuntu.com/questions/18091/ubuntu-extras-keyring-error resolves this for me.  This a residual issue, after attempts to update (with errors).  ***Do you need this is in more detail?***

Comment: @david6 Thanks but the option number five doesn't work for me. I found [this great questions](http://askubuntu.com/q/13065/62483).